# Removing carriage return from beginning of string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, carriage-return

I understand how to remove carriage returns from the ends of strings -- but I'm running into an issue in a Perl script of mine where a carriage return is found *before* the string.

For example, my script searches for strings which start with an exclamation mark, but a line that causes problems in my script is: `^C!`

Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: Seems like this could be done more easily done without using regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^C` is not the `cat -v` representation of carriage return, but of [ETX](http://enwp.org/End-of-text_character), maybe that's the source of your confusion. `s/\cC//` will remove it.

Check with [Devel::Peek](http://p3rl.org/Devel%3a%3aPeek)::Dump from within Perl or [uniquote](http://p3rl.org/uniquote) from outside for other invisible characters.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a regexpr to clean that characters:

```
$line =~ s/^[^!]//;
```